# Sections of Appendix are also visible on the "Content" page

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am writing a thesis, which contains appendices with different sections.

**PROBLEM:** The sections of the Appendices are visible on the "Content" page because it considers Appendix as a normal chapter which has many sections.

**I am not sure if it correct to show the sections of the Appendix on the TOC page.**

Please suggest, how can I hide the section details of Appendix on the TOC page.

Comment: try `\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}`

Comment: @touhami: In case there is more details on the class I would suggest to post an answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer as you say.

Comment: Skm: Auf deutsch: Ich würde mal ein paar Antworten zu einigen Fragen akzeptieren, da gibt es durchaus Möglichkeiten;-) -- das zeigt den Respekt gegenüber den Leuten hier, die einige Zeit investieren.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I totally understand your point. But I cannot accept an answer that has not solved the problem because it will mislead people in future. Whenever an answer has helped and proved to be correct, I have always accepted it along with a Thanks note. :)

Answer (score 2):

If the appendix sections shouldn't be numbered → use `\section*`

Otherwise hide the sections with a special trick:

Since the `tocdepth` counter is important for `LaTeX` to decide which structuring level appears in the `ToC` it's enough to say `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` written to the ToC file. `0` stands for `chapter` level, which is above `section` so only chapters or parts would be written to the `ToC`, since `chapters` aren't available in a standard class, there's nothing written at all.

I've added a `\ifhideappendixstuffintoc` switch which does hide the appendix sections based on a condition.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifhideappendixstuffintoc

\hideappendixstuffintoctrue % yes, hide it! 

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@apendix\appendix % Store the original \appendix command

\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \latex@@appendix%
  \ifhideappendixstuffintoc
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}% \protect is not really necessary, otherwise it will show \global \c@tocdepth 0\relax in the ToC file
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Main part section}
\clearpage
\appendix
\section{Section in Appendix}
\end{document}
```